# semicolon error in javascript for loop in internet explorer 10 and lower version of ie

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

Hello everyone I have an issue related Internet Explorer 10 and older version,

my code is running properly in all the browser

> (Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer 11)

but when i tried to run that in Internet Explorer 10 and 9 I am getting the error of

> SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'google.map.js (1270,14)

and on that particular line i have a for loop

```
for (let i = 0; i < Markers.length; i++) {
```

and my full function

```
function clearMarker() {
    for (let i = 0; i < Markers.length; i++) {
        Markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    Markers = new Array();
}
```

i don't understand why this error is coming in my console. and this is working fine in other browsers,

is it related to compatibility of ie 10 and lesser?

Comment: `let` is not supported in IE10. In IEs it was first introduced in IE11, but didn't create a block scope.

Comment: Change from `let` to `var` ... `for (var i = 0; i < Markers.length; i++) {`

Comment: Are you working on a node environment or writing code directly in the html/js files?

Comment: You can check browser support here. https://caniuse.com/#search=let . As you can see from the URL, IE 11 is the lowest version partially supporting `let`. So you should use `var` instead.

Comment: I am working on jquery with mvc @AseemUpadhyay

Comment: Microsoft has sunlighted IE 11 and reited anythgin below. DON'T SUPPORT THEM! Support Edge, Firefox, Safari and Chrome if possible, or just Edge and Chrome for safety(Safari has breaking Date problems among other foolery, and Firefox is just broken for large JSON parsing among other problems)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`let` and `const` are not valid in IE 10 or below and worse yet they don't work right in IE 11! You shouldn't use them. You should change the `let` to a `var`.

You can find more information at [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=let) about what browsers will support it or the [MDN article on `let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#browser%20compatability)

Comment: I would also suggest to use something like babel to convert ES6 script into "regular" JS.

Comment: that's way out of scope for this question